# Monitor mode disables WiFi Connectivity

Tags: kali-linux, monitoring

After going through a lot of blogs and forums, I've come to know that the TP-LINK TL-WN722N supports monitor mode for packet sniffing. Tecently, I bought the same device and tried monitor mode with the following commands in Kali:

```
airmon-ng check kill
airmon-ng start wlan1
```

Soon after when I run iwconfig, I could see wlan1mon and monitor mode is turned ON successfully.

The problem is I cannot connect to any website from that point.

1. Is this the default behaviour?
2. I'm doing these things as a root, is that right?
3. Do I need the latest PC/laptop for doing such things?

I'm using a Lenovo G550 bought seven years ago.

Comment: Usually, an interface in monitor mode cannot be used as a regular interface.

Comment: @RonMaupin , Does that still sniff packets though it cannot act as regular interface?

Comment: In my experience, interfaces in monitor mode do not pass the traffic up the network stack, so while in monitor mode, the interface cannot be used as a regular interface for things like web browsing. You are either sniffing or networking, but not both at once. If you pass sniffed traffic up the network stack, it will start sending rejections back out for traffic which was never destined to your host. That seems to defeat the purpose of silently sniffing traffic.

Answer (score 0):

```
   1.Is this the default behavior?
```

- Yes. While you are in monitor mode you can not use internet. You have to update that in managed mode again to use internet.

  ```
  2.I'm doing these things as a root, is that right?
  ```
- You have to . Otherwise you can never access or use that software.

  ```
  3.Do I need the latest PC/laptop for doing such things?
  ```
- PC has nothing to do with this. If you can install aircrack all you need is a driver suitable with your accessories. And you have to use the v1 of 722. If it is v2/v3 there are other driver you have to activate manually.